# Using two identifiers in uri

Tags: php, api-platform.com

I got a table that was partitionned on a datetime column.

If i let the get item of ApiPlateform, the query will check all partitions to found the item.

I'd like to be able to send also the date on the uri

```
<?php

#[ApiResource(
operations: [
new Get(uriTemplate: '/entities/{id}/{date}'),
)]
#[NeedLegacyConversion]
class Invoice
{
    protected ?string $id = null;
    protected ?\DateTime $date = null;
}
```

I'm a litle bit lost on it.

i try a lot of stuff (too many to remember) with `uriVariables` but nothing work.

I like the uri got 2 identifiers

Edit:
I was abble to use the datetime on uri using
ApiProperty:identifier on the both properties
define uriVariable on the Get for exemple

But there is a bug on APIP that can use datetime on identifier but crahs when it try to link an item and the identifiers to generete iris. It want a scalar value and fail to get a datetime :(

Answer (score 0):

It's called composite key. I am not sure if API-Platform finally supports that. You can try by adding the attribute on the properties that should be your composite key:

```
#[ApiProperty(identifier: true)]
protected ?string $id = null;

#[ApiProperty(identifier: true)]
protected ?\DateTime $date = null;
```

Your uriTemplate would already fit this configuration.

If APIP does not already support that, you could implement a Doctrine Query Extension that is able to work with composite keys.

**If it is only about the IRI** (and in your database you just have a single key) you want to look at implementing a custom `IriConverterInterface` to allow using the DateTime object in the IRI.

*PS: In this case you don't need the above ApiProperty attributes.*